# File Sharing on Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

Is there a way to allow access the folder on server for reading only for every user, who access server via explorer. Active Directory is disabled, and there is a workgroup here. Everytime I try to access folder which is shared(file server is enabled, read is marked for all)I'm asked to type in login and password, which usual user doesn't know. Thank you! I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Try remove "File possword protect sharing" and check the outcome.

To disable password protected sharing on Windows Server 2008, please do the following:

In the Sharing and Discovery section of the Network and Sharing Center window, click the down arrow next to Password protected sharing.

Within the Password protected sharing settings, click Turn off password protected sharing, and then click Apply.

Hope this helps.